# Determine from Apex whether a user's session is invalid

Tags: apex, identity, session

Can anyone think of a way, *from within Apex*, to tell if a User's session has expired / been invalidated?

Our app is very JS Remoting intensive, so it would be nice if we were able to detect, from within a `@RemoteAction` annotated method, whether a User's session has expired. Or does anyone know, will the Session Id, as returned from `UserInfo.getSessionId(),` be `null` if it has expired / been invalidated?

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just handle the exception in your remoting javascript?

Comment: Daniel, the 'Visualforce Remoting Exception' is thrown by Visualforce's internal JavaScript, as a result of AJAX, so it's pretty difficult to catch.

Comment: That's frustrating, I didn't think it would throw an exception, but return an error ajax response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your apex won't be run if there will be a timeout (meaning that for all practical purposes you can treat `UserInfo.getSessionId()` as never null).

Can you wrap your methods in **client-side check**?

```
var currentTime=new Date().getTime();
var sessionTimeLeft=secondsLeftValue-((currentTime-lastPageActivityTime)/1000);
alert(sessionTimeLeft);
```

It's based on stuff you can see when you view page source a bit under `<form  id="sessiontimeout"`...

---

Alternatively maybe you can make a simple call to server from JS before calling actual remoteAction?

See [sample calls in the AJAX toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm).
You'd have to query for something or perhaps retrieve something really small:

```
var result = sforce.connection.getServerTimestamp();
log(result.timestamp);

var user = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();
log("Hello " + user.userName);
log("Your email id is " + user.userEmail);
log("and you work for " + user.organizationName);
```

But I recall reading somewhere we shouldn't mix VF and the `connection.js` library...

Comment: Yes, I had thought about that, as it would work for session timeout detection client-side, but what if the user's session has been invalidated or they've been logged out? When that happens the client just gets thrown hidden/unseen `Visualforce Remoting Exception' messages, which are very difficult to trap client-side using try/catch. So the client user thinks the app's broken, when it's actually there session that's been invalidated, not timed-out.

Comment: I think this might be the right route in general, with some changes.  You've got a catch 22 trying the Apex route, because anything that will legitimately reach Apex will need a session ID, etc.

It sounds like the user is leaving the interface open, and say - returning from lunch.  I would setup a distinct loop to track idleness, like a global countdown which gets reset everytime your JS Remoting gets a success back.  If the countdown gets to like an hour (though I think sessions might be 2), block the UI and force the user to do a session check.

Comment: I think @joshbirk is right on this one, trying to catch this from Apex is a Catch-22, and I think that with regards to RemoteActions, which my question was targeted at, eyescream's idea about doing a 2-step check is what makes the most sense: 1) check to see if the Session Timeout interval has expired (this info is stored in a global JS variable set by Salesforce (allowing their little 'session is about to expire' popup window to work) 2) try to catch VF Remoting Exceptions / do dummy calls to AJAX toolkit. The dummy calls though consume API calls, so are non-ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom web service to test whether the session is valid and then make a web service request to check this (if you wanted to use the token).

You would need to define a web service that would simply return true if the user could access it. Then expose this as a web service and generate the wsdl file for it before reimporting it to make the call.

Alternatively, look at something like the FinancialForce metadata wrapper https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi - just attempt to login to that. If your session Id is valid you will be able to login otherwise you will not.

Comment: I like the idea of doing a callout to Salesforce for a `login`, but that requires doing a callout every time the user runs a Remoting function --- not ideal.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I agree, but you could then cache it with some sort of timer to know whether you need to think about checking again?

Comment: Yes, the timer caching is a good idea as well.